# Improve WPF application performance by splitting components like React

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application which has very complex XAML files. In React, splitting components helps improve performance because it prevents browser from rerendering when condition (props, state, etc.) doesn't change.

Could this technique be applied to WPF? In other words, if I divide a single XAML file into several components, could it help improve performance?

Comment: how on earth is this question not clear enough? Would love to answer but now can't. Voting to have it re-open.

Comment: Yes, that could help. Depending on many other things you haven't mentioned, so please provide more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> helps improve performance

WPF renders much faster than HTML. I only observed rendering performance issues in WPF when I did something really stupid, like creating a million of visual elements (by disabling virtualization in a long list), or re-creating elements in every frame rendered.

> it prevents browser from rerendering when condition (props, state, etc.) doesn't change

WPF does that automatically for unchanged pieces of visual tree, regardless of how the tree was made.

> In other words, if I divide a single XAML file into several components, could it help improve performance?

Very unlikely. But it can help you work on the software. XAML is no different from source code, if you have a file with 10000 lines, consider moving larger pieces into new files.

Comment: I would rather suggest creating `UserControl` (separate piece/component) only if that component will be used more than once at some different places (after all i see no benefit of splitting app in parts except reusability of components ).

Comment: the notion that WPF is somehow faster than HTML does not reflect reality. WPF is often incredibly slow, particularly when it comes to text rendering, deep hierarchies or rendering lots of tiny elements. Try make a browser in WPF and you'd see just how slow it is.

Comment: @PatrickKlug You're right about hypothetical web browser, but people don't use WPF like that. WPF is used for making apps, not for rendering HTML. Templating, data binding, virtualization are example of features missing in HTML5 (emulated in JavaScript frameworks, poorly) which are at the core of WPF and they help a lot with performance.

Comment: "WPF renders much faster than HTML" is simply false. you have nothing to support this claim.

Comment: @PatrickKlug I witnessed many apps I use moved from WPF to Electron. One example is github.

Answer (score 0):

Use WPF Control.

Reference document: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:~:text=Windows%20Presentation%20Foundation%20(WPF)%20ships,been%20referred%20to%20as%20controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#:%7E:text=Windows%20Presentation%20Foundation%20(WPF)%20ships,been%20referred%20to%20as%20controls).